# Can I use Timeshift to go back to a previous release of Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, downgrade, timeshift

I recently attempted an upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.  During the process I got stuck whilst comparing 2 versions of a config file.

Foolishly I used ctrl+c and unknowingly aborted the upgrade. The system was no longer booting.

I was then advised to do a manual upgrade from a bootable USB using the 'Something Else' option and just installing over the half upgraded stuff, which I did.  However ALL my installed apps like Rails etc are no longer accessible or working although all of the code is there.

I had taken a Timeshift snapshot immediately before starting the upgrade. Those snapshots are still on a different disk partition.  However Timeshift itself isn't working.

If I reinstall Timeshift would I be able to revert back to 16.04 using the snapshot?  If I can, is there anything I ought to be vary of?

Thanks for any advice offered.

Comment: My understanding is that if you boot to a Ubuntu Live, you can install Timeshift there, and restore your previous snapshot.

Comment: @hynennema thanks.  Unfortunately I have already upgraded to 18.04.  So the main question is whether I can move BACK to a previous release rather than just to previous versions of the SAME release.

Comment: I was talking about restoring a prior snapshot from 16.04. You said that you couldn't boot to 18.04 after an aborted upgrade. Will it work? I don't know. If not, you'll just have to reinstall Ubuntu... either version.

Comment: @heynnema I did install 18.04 using the 'Something Else' option from a bootable USB.  Hence my question about whether I can go back to a previous release with Timeshift.

Comment: My suggestion was to try it. You can't do much more damage than what has already been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @heynnema's suggestion to try the restore I installed Timeshift on the new 18.04 system and during initial configuration of Timeshift I pointed the location to where the previous snapshots were.  This offered me those snapshots and I restored from the one that I had manually created immediately before starting the upgrade.

The restore started properly and I could see all the files being restored inside a Terminal session.  However half way through the screen went blank and I could not log back in again.  The disk drive light was still working so I left it alone and after about 1 hour the system rebooted and .....I've got my OLD 16.04 configuration back!!!

I had been reluctant to try the restore because in one of the comments on this article :

https://itsfoss.com/backup-restore-linux-timeshift/

someone had said that they had tried to restore back from 20.04 to 18.04 but had been left with an unsuccessful and unbootable system.

I hope my experience will be of use to someone in the future and I would like to thank @heynnema for urging me to try the restore.

I would also like to Thank Tony George and all the other contributors to Timeshift for such an amazing and life saving piece of software.